# suppress effect of submitButton on startup of shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with a reactive bit of UI which is used to filter my data. I then use the data for plotting. My reactive bit of UI checks all possible values of a variable, offers them as choices in a `selectizeInput` and starts with all of the choices selected. In my actual app changes in the filter can take quite a bit of time to run so I have `submitButton` to prevent the app from constantly updating. The only problem is on the initial startup of the app: It loads the choices in to the dynamic UI and selects them, but because further reactivity is blocked by the `submitButton`, this information doesn't reach the plot and so it shows an empty plot. All that's needed to get the desired result is hit the `sumbitButton` once. Once this is done the app works as desired.

I'm looking for a way to make the plot show initially without having to press the `submitButton`. In my following toy example this could probably be done quite easily by replacing the `submitButton` with an `actionButton` so that not all reactivity is frozen, which seems to be the solution in a lot of problems involving `submitButton`s in other question. However, in my actual app there are numerous inputs and sources of reactivity so configuring the `actionButton` and capturing all desired effects in `observeEvent`s would be quite tedious when the `submitButton` does all of this with the only problem being the startup. Are there any other ways I can make the plot show on the first startup but follow the `submitButton` behavior from then on?

An example app:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
      uiOutput("Cylselectui"),
      submitButton("Apply changes")
    ),
    mainPanel(
     plotOutput("Carsplot") 
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Carsplot <- renderPlot({
    plotdata <- subset(mtcars, cyl %in% input$Cylselection) #Filter based on cyl

    ggplot(plotdata, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, colour = factor(cyl))) + #Create plot
      geom_point()
  })

  output$Cylselectui <- renderUI({ #Create the cyl selectize ui based on the values of cyl that are in the data
    selectizeInput(
      'Cylselection', 'Select by Cylinder', 
      choices = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)),
      selected = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `reactive` to check whether the input is null (first time) and then provide your defaults values:

```
  Cylselection <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$Cylselection)) 
       sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)) 
    else 
       input$Cylselection})

  output$Carsplot <- renderPlot({
    plotdata <- subset(mtcars, cyl %in% Cylselection()) #Filter based on cyl
    ggplot(plotdata, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, colour = factor(cyl))) + #Create plot
      geom_point()
  })
```

More elegant is to put your data subset in the reactive:

```
  plotdata <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$Cylselection)) 
      mtcars
    else 
      subset(mtcars, cyl %in% input$Cylselection)})

  output$Carsplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(plotdata(), aes(x = mpg, y = hp, colour = factor(cyl))) + #Create plot
      geom_point()
  })
```